# Как подсчитать количество значений из БД и передать в AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Есть модель

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
    public Owner()
    {
        Pets = new List<Pet>();
    }
}
```

Api-controller

```
private OwnersAndPetsContext db = new OwnersAndPetsContext();
    // GET api/values
    public IQueryable<Owner> GetOwners()
    {
        return db.Owners.Include(b => b.Pets); ;
    }
```

Кусок кода из Index.cshtml

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:800px">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <td>Name</td>
        <th>Pets Count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="owner in owners">
        <td>{{ owner.Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ owner.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ owner.Pets }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Создал базу один ко многим. Как в столбец Pets Count выводит кол-во значений, а не сами значения?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

что бы получить количество *животных* следует воспользоваться методом `Count()` который вернет кол-во объектов в коллекции

---

я бы наверно создал класс модель для конкретного `view`

```
public class OwnersViewModel
{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int PetCount {get;set;}

}
```

метод возвращающий список *владельцев* я переписал так:

```
public IEnumerable<OwnersViewModel> GetOwners()
{

    using(var db = new OwnersAndPetsContext())
    {
        return db.Owners.Include(x=>x.Pets)
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(x=> new OwnersViewModel{
                     Id = x.Id,
                     Name = x.Name,
                     PetCount = x.Pets.Count()
                 });
    }

}
```